# Why are props being modified when clicking on a route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I start with these two links on my summary page.

[image]

I'll click on the first link and everything displays properly, I don't make any changes and click the Home link.

[image]

Here are my console logs:

[image]

However, when I click on the second link and click the home button without making any changes, my uuid(s) for milk and oreo are being changed.

[image]

My redux state is correct, so I know my state is not being modified.

[image]

My components related to the display of the Summary Page are the MealList and MealItem components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import MealItem from './MealItem'

const MealList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.meals.length === 0 ? (
                <div>
                    <span>No Meals</span>
                </div>
            ) : (
                    props.meals.map(meal =>
                        <MealItem key={meal.uuid} {...meal} />
                    )
                )}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    meals: state.meals
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MealList);
```

And:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'



const MealItem = (props) => {
    console.log(props.uuid);
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to={`/edit/${props.uuid}`}>
                <h1>{props.foodItem}</h1>
            </Link>
            <h3>{props.calories}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}



export default MealItem
```

The page that renders the EditMealPage is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { editServing } from './actions/meal';

class EditMealPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            uuid: this.props.meal.uuid,
            foodId: this.props.meal.foodId,
            measureURI: this.props.meal.measureURI,
            quantity: this.props.meal.quantity,
            mealCategory: this.props.meal.mealCategory
        }
    }

    onMeasureChange = e => (this.setState({ measureURI: e.target.value }))
    onQuantityChange = e => (this.setState({ quantity: e.target.value }))
    onMealCategoryChange = e => (this.setState({ mealCategory: e.target.value }))

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { foodId, measureURI, quantity, uuid, mealCategory } = this.state
        const editsObj = {
            foodId,
            measureURI,
            quantity: parseInt(quantity)
        }
        this.props.editServing(uuid, editsObj, mealCategory)

    }

    render() {
        const { foodItem, calories, measures } = this.props.meal
        const { measureURI, quantity, mealCategory } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Edit Meal</h1>
                <h3>{foodItem}</h3>
                <h3>{calories}</h3>
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <select
                            value={measureURI}
                            onChange={this.onMeasureChange}>
                            {measures.map((measure, i) => <option key={i} value={measure.uri}>{measure.label}</option>)}
                        </select>
                        <input
                            value={quantity}
                            onChange={this.onQuantityChange}
                            type="text"></input>
                        <select value={mealCategory}
                            onChange={this.onMealCategoryChange}>
                            <option value='breakfast'>Breakfast</option>
                            <option value='lunch'>Lunch</option>
                            <option value='dinner'>Dinner</option>
                            <option value='snack'>Snack</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit">Edit Meal</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    meal: state.meals.find(meal => meal.uuid = props.match.params.uuid)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    editServing: (uuid, fetchObj, mealCategory) => dispatch(editServing(uuid, fetchObj, mealCategory))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditMealPage)
```

I can't figure out why my uuid prop is being modified.  It seems this is the only prop that is modified, In my routes file the uuid is the only parameter I use `<Route path='/edit/:uuid' component={EditMealPage} />`  What am I doing wrong?

The link to the GitHub repo is https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat if needed.

Comment: You should access your uuid parameter with match object provided by react-router. You can wrap your EditMealPage.js component with withRouter hoc and then get access to match property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. I wouldn't have checked if not for Danilo's comment. It's a classic mistake and often hard to spot:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    meal: state.meals.find(meal => meal.uuid = props.match.params.uuid)
})
```

You are assigning `meal.uuid` the value of `props.match.params.uuid` with `=`, whereas you just want to check equality with `===`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's happening here with these pieces of code, (we'd probably need the reducers too) so I took the liberty of downloading your repo and trying it locally (that included creating an API key in the API you're using to retrieve food).

Having said that, after testing it locally, I found the problem and it is... a typo!

checkout [this line](https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat/blob/master/src/components/EditMealPage.js#L69)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    meal: state.meals.find(meal => meal.uuid = props.match.params.uuid)
})
```

let's look closer on the arrow function inside the `find`... you're doing an assignment instead of an equals. (`=` vs `===`)

replacing it with

```js
meal => meal.uuid === props.match.params.uuid
```

will solve your issue

Comment: I appreciate your taking out the time to set up everything to help Debug.

Comment: no problem! I thought the issue was in the reducers. Eventually, I found the typo, but it turned out that part of the code was already in the question.